# Has Tomcat changed the way it handles absolute/relative paths between 9.0.20 and 9.0.63

Tags: jsp, tomcat, tomcat9

I upgraded my Tomcat from 9.0.20 to 9.0.63 (the latest available in Azure SaaS, at the time of writing)

My application breaks, and Tomcat seems unable to resolve `includes`

```
<%@ include file="../../../../../obj/PG.jsp"%>
```

The error returned is:

```
0-Jul-2023 12:21:06.546 SEVERE [http-nio-172.16.1.4-80-exec-3] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for 
servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [/myapp/v/p/l/lm.jsp 
(line: [4], column: [1]) JSP file [../../../../../obj/PG.jsp] not found] with root cause
```

I have looked in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html but cannot see any changes which might have affected this.

I see a similar question here [Tomcat 9.0.67 <%@ include dont work in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73957924/tomcat-9-0-67-include-dont-work-in-some-cases) but it is for different version numbers.

I imagine that I could update all the references throughout the entire application and I could get it to work, but does anyone know why the error is happening, and how to solve it easily on an application level.